# Double for loop in pandas where the index is time in days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a question regarding using a double for loop. My idea is to loop through time and location, say I have 10 days and 10 locations and I want to store the number of customers at each location each day. I am storing the number of customers in a blank df with the index as time. However, I'm having a bit of trouble looping through the 10 locations. Below is a manual method I used:

```
period = 10
location = 10
periods = np.arange(period)
locations = np.arange(location)
default_customers = 500
df = pd.DataFrame(index = periods, columns = 'customers1','customers2').fillna(0)
for i in locations:
    for j in periods:
        df['customers1'][j] = default_customers
        df['customers2'][j] = default_customers
```

Is it possible to loop through the locations instead of having to create a column for each of them? Thanks!

Edit:
The expected dataframe would be like this, so that I can track the number of customers and attributes for each location on a daily basis. I think it works if I just make 10 columns but there must be a method to simplify this.

```
day|sales at loc1|sales at loc2|Avg sale price loc1|Avg sale price loc2
...|...          | ...         |...                |...
```

Comment: Can you give an example dataframe of what you expect/would like the output to look like?

Comment: show your expected dataframe. it would be helpful to make an answer

Comment: Thanks, I edited it to add the df I outputted.

Comment: How does your desired result relate to your posted code? There is no sales or average or customers. You appear to fill every cell of data frame with 500.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case anyone ever runs into the same problem.
I ended up using a function to loop the days, and then used a loop for each location which calls this function. Probably not the best solution but gets the job done. Ex:

```
for i in locations:
    run function(loop for j in periods)
```